# Выпадающий список в django

Tags: python, django

Пишу простенький интернет-магазин на **Django 1.9**.
Имеются следующие модели:

*tovar/models.py*

```
class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(verbose_name="Цвет", max_length=25, blank=False, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name="Код цвета", max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)

class Tovar(models.Model):
    color = models.ManyToManyField(Color, blank=True)
```

*cart/models.py*

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(verbose_name="Цвет", max_length=25, blank=False, null=True)
```

В таблице **Cart** приложения cart указан список цветов определённого товара которые должны браться из таблицы **Tovar** (поля ManyToManyField).


От сюда вопрос: как мне написать соответствующую форму поля color модели Tovar? Если использовать виджет SelectMultiple то как реализовать вывод ManyToManyField?

Answer (score 3):

Можно в шаблоне с помощью цикла в тегах `<select><option>` разместить нужную информацию из полей, а затем подключить [плагин на JQuery](https://www.positronx.io/multiselect-dropdown-list-with-checkboxes-jquery-plugin/) для красивого мультиселекта.

```
<select class="yourclass" multiple="" name="yourname" required="" id="yourselectid"> 
  {% for m in model_context %}
      <option value="{{ m.somevalue }}">{{ m.somename }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

В вашем кастомном .js файле можно манипулировать этой штукой, обращаясь к параметру `id` тега `<select>`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourselectid').multiselect({
        columns: 1,
        placeholder: 'Какая-то надписька для поля',
        search: false,
        selectAll: true
    });
});
```

Передавать инфу из этой штуки можно по нажатию на кнопку, её надо в HTML создать.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send-button").click(function() {
        var fdata = $("#yourForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_calls/your_path/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: fdata,
            success : function(json) {
                alert("Successfully sent the URL to Django");
            },
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                alert("Could not send URL to Django. Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Да, при такой схеме можно не создавать форму вообще. Вся магия происходит в **views.py** и **custom.js**.

Answer (score 0):

Привет!

Не уверен, что сработает, но попробуй так:

```
class TovarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    tovars = MultipleChoiceField(choices=Tovar.objects.all())
```